# Is there a way to commit to Azure Dev Ops repositories without triggering pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have code stored inside various branches an Azure Dev Ops git repository.

**Is it possible that a developer can somehow push to a branch, passing some sort of command line flag, that will stop any pipelines executing for that branch?**

I have a number of pipelines that are set to run when changes are detected to my branches.

Workflow:

1. Developer pulls down branch (e.g. `features/abc`)
2. Developer pushes changes to that branch

My `pipeline.yml` file is then set up as follows:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - features/*
```

When the developer pushes to the `feature/abc` that will start the pipeline.

I am wondering if there is some sort of flag I can set on the command line when I enter `git push` that will stop the pipeline from executing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah this is possible, one such way is to include [skip ci] in the commit message.

A full list of ways can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) under the section header "Skipping CI for individual pushes"